# SQL: How to write multiple interactive scripts in one query (insert rows)

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

Simple question- I just want to learn how to write a query that will insert 2 rows into my table by writing one query, instead of 2 separate ones. My queries work completely fine, I just want to know a simpler way, if that's possible. Below are my 2 queries that I'd like to combine into 1.

```
INSERT INTO dept (deptno, dname)
VALUES (dept_id_seq.NEXTVAL, 'EDUCATION');

INSERT INTO dept (deptno, dname)
VALUES (dept_id_seq.NEXTVAL, 'ADMINISTRATION');
```

As I stated above, my code works as expected. Here is my output with NO errors-

```
DE DNAME                          LOC
-- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
10 ACCOUNTING                     NEW YORK
20 RESEARCH                       DALLAS
30 SALES                          CHICAGO
40 OPERATIONS                     BOSTON
60 EDUCATION
70 ADMINISTRATION
```

Thank you for anyone's help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not totally clear what you're asking for, but you can make your inserts 1 script execution with:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO dept (deptno, dname) VALUES (dept_id_seq.NEXTVAL, 'EDUCATION');
INSERT INTO dept (deptno, dname) VALUES (dept_id_seq.NEXTVAL, 'ADMINISTRATION');
END;
```

However it looks like you may want to use a cursor to loop through the list of values and insert them somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I'm looking for, but after I press enter to execute, it just keeps adding a new line in the command line. I can't exit out.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are describing.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what would you consider, but you can do it like this:

`INSERT INTO dept`

`SELECT dept_id_seq.NEXTVAL, 'EDUCATION' UNION ALL`

`SELECT dept_id_seq.NEXTVAL, 'ADMINISTRATION'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following syntax:

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Comment: Thank you. I have to write SELECT * FROM dual on the last line?

Comment: @strudel: if you're using `SELECT ALL` you have to do something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use a `MERGE` with only the `NOT MATCHED` branch filled in:

```
MERGE INTO DEPT d
  USING (SELECT 'EDUCATION' AS DNAME FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 'ADMINISTRATION' AS DNAME FROM DUAL) s
    ON (d.DNAME = s.DNAME)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (DEPTNO, DNAME)
    VALUES (DEPT_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, s.DNAME)
```